# Identify IP address / hosting of inner pages

Tags: ip-address, local-seo, subdirectory, reverse-proxy

Working on a website which an SEO agency had previously done lots of spammy work on and built loads of duplicate home pages in subfolders just with a different locals in the title and URLs.

However we have built a new site, changed their hosting but these pages are still live. We are pretty confident they aren't on the server any more so I think they must be hosted elsewhere.

I think you can do this with a reverse proxy? Host content on another server but make it appear on the domain.

How can we identify the IP address of inner pages? When I use an IP checker online, it always defaults back to the root domain.

Comment: *it always defaults back to the root domain* And it always will. The domain name is tied to only one IP address (generally). If you have full control over the domain name and the host/IP address, then there is nothing else. What is it you are seeing exactly that makes you think the old pages are still out there? That might help us to know how to help.

Comment: The pages are indexed in Google and still accessible when you click on them.

Comment: I was not being trite when I asked that question. It is a lead. If you click on the link, do you see your access in your log files?? Keep in mind that it takes a period of time to get the access from cache to file if Apache sometimes. You may have to wait a while and check the log file again. Keep track of the computer time when you click on the link.

Answer (score 1):

If the files that produce the page represent code other than html then look for lines that point to remote URLs or IP addresses.

For example, if the original home page content is on another server like you claim, and the file responsible for homepage content is index.php then the original file might be intact and you might have been given the copy of index.php that contains code to connect to the remote server and print the results. Since your php file is doing the initial processing in this case, the domain will still be your new domain.

Just do a search on all your files for anything that looks like IP addresses or any references to websites.

Also, if the website is enhanced enough, it could be possible that javascript was modified enough to the point where users download content from a remote server in order for the site to appear complete.